# Error when adding Facebook login to iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am following [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial/) to add Facebook login to my iPhone app.

However, when I add `[FBLoginView class];` to `didFinishLoadingWithOptions` in my `AppDelegate.m`, I get the following error:

`Use of undeclared identifier: 'FBLoginView'`

To my knowledge I have added the SDK properly including everything listed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started).

The whole code looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Makes various cosmetic changes
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor: UIColorFromRGB(0x007aff)];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
    // The code that FB told me to add
    [FBLoginView class];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import facebook SDK. use this line in `AppDelegate`.h.

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

Comment: I knew it'd be something obvious! Fixed - will accept in 8 mins.

Comment: Great!!! I spend about hour trying to fix it! It's not mentioned in Facebook SDK docs btw. +1